# How to set 'Second' in android time picker?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I need a Time Picker for getting hour minutes and second but I could not find a way to get second from time picker. Is there any way to select second from time picker?

Comment: if you are allowed to use some other widget you can use - https://github.com/IvanKovac/TimePickerWithSeconds

Comment: Yeah, I created a time picker view with a second as I could not get the seconds value from the official time picker.  Thanks everyone for your views